# next/navigation Link with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to display a tsx component on a new tab but I want to pass props into the new page. Basically I want the tsx equivalent of something like this in flutter:

```dart
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page({title: example, desc: example2})),
)
```

I have yet to find a way using the next/navigation package and I am unsure if it is ok to mix `next/navigation` and `next/link` Links as I am still new to Next.js.

Answer (score 0):

to achive your request using 'next/link' to navigate between pages and apss props to the new page, you can do it something like this:

from sender page:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';

const SenderPage = () => {
  const example = 'Title Example';
  const example2 = 'Description Example';

  return (
    <Link
      href={{
        pathname: '/page', // Replace with path of your page component
        query: { title: example, desc: example2 }
      }}
      passHref
    >
      <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        Open Page in New Tab
      </a>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default SenderPage;
```

for receiver page:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { title, desc } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <p>{desc}</p>
      {/* Other content */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

**1. Router**

In the receiver page (the one that receives the props), we use the useRouter hook to access the query parameters sent from the sender page. By doing this, we ensure that the page has access to the props being passed through the URL.

**2.Link**

The **href prop** specifies the path to the destination page, which you replace with the actual path of your page component (like '/page').

The **query** object inside the href prop is used to pass query parameters to the linked page. In your example, you're using it to pass the title and desc props.

The **passHref** prop ensures that the underlying  tag generated by the Link component contains the href attribute with the correct URL. This is important for maintaining proper behavior and accessibility.

More information:

[NextJs documentation Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)

[Linking and Navigation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating)

[Routing begginer guide FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/routing-in-nextjs-beginners-guide/)